# Django cron-job for user-specified times

Tags: django, cron, rabbitmq, celery

I am wanting to send notifications based on a user-specified time. IE, in google calendar, I can receive a text message when my task time is hit.

Is the solution to this to run a cron job, have it execute every minute and scan which users have a time equaling the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `celery`, I assume you have celery running. You could use the `eta` kwarg to `apply_async()` to schedule a task to run at a specific time, see here:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

If you need to use a cron job, I would not check if `notification_time == current_time`, but rather track unsent notifications with a boolean `is_sent` field on the model and check for `notification_time <= current_time and not is_sent`. This seems to be slightly less error prone. You could also add some form of check to prevent mass-sending notifications in case your system goes down for a few hours.